# Generating function problem follow

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

There are $30$ kinds of gifts that will be distributed to $50$ peoples with each people getting at least $1$ gift. How many possible ways are there?

the answer using generating function.
Any hints or idea?

Comment: How many gifts of each kind are there?

Comment: Assuming each fruit is infinite in number, and that you have basic idea about generating functions, Generating function for any fruit will $$x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$$ you don't have to worry about the power exceeding 50

Comment: @AshWhole You seem to be assuming that each type of gift will be distributed to at least one person, and that no one will get more than one of the same kind of gift.  Neither of these conditions is stated in the problem.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @saulspatz, oh yeah. You're right. Should have included 1. Though, I said it's generating function for "any" gift, by that I simply meant all gifts will have same function

Comment: Though now I think there's some flaw in the question without knowing the number of each gift. I also don't know why I read it as fruit LoL

Comment: the problem wasn't completed with the number of each gift

Comment: how ${}{}{}{}$ ????

Comment: Number of way is $0$ ? Since the coefficient of $x^{30}$ in the expansion $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)^{50}$ is $0$.